# Why is an HTML section element not altered by CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have an HTML section that I am trying to alter with CSS:

```
<section class="jumbo">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>THIS IS THE TEXT CONTAINED WITHIN THE JUMBO</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

However the changes I make in my CSS file, such as changing the color of the text contained in the element are not having any affect:

```
#jumbo {
  background-image: url("../images/carbon.jpeg");
  background-position: center center;
  min-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

#jumbo h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

Do you have any tips for how I can debug an issue like this?

[image]

Comment: Because `jumbo` is a **class** and you are selecting it as an ID `#`.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.jumbo`.

More about CSS selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2):

`#jumbo` is an id selector

you should use a class selector

`.jumbo` and `.jumbo h1`